# How can I edit the order of stops of an existing line without having to start over in Cities in Motion 2

Tags: cities-in-motion-2

This was a much requested feature in the first Cities in Motion, surely it has added so that you can somehow re-order the stops?

I don't want to keep deleting all of my stops, just because I want to change the order of a stop at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no way to directly edit or re-order the stops.** What you can do is delete all the stops up to the point where you want to detour a new stop, then add new ones, then add the rest of your stops back. It's kind of a pain (they really need a drag-and-drop) but that's the current implementation. I realize you asked this question [here](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?680244)  but I'm summarizing it for others.

Comment: Thanks, I realised there that if you're adding a stop residing on the existing path of your line, it will automatically fit it in between automatically, which is at least something.

Comment: I've played this game for about 8 years now and just learned after finding this Q & A that this feature exists. I was always under the impression I had to delete and re-create stops in order to create a new stop between two existing stops or to create a detour. I just tested it and it works for a new stop between two existing stops (like the comment Apr 4 '13 describes) and it also works for detours. I created a new stop not between two existing stops on the path, and it added the stop just after the nearest stop that could get to it, effectively creating a detour. This is pretty nice.